# How to relate a data but only if before a specific date?

Tags: mysql, powerbi, business-intelligence

Basically table1 look something like this

```
DATE       ID        PCS
1/2/2019   DIE6660   8
1/2/2019   DIE9240   9
2/2/2019   DIE9240   7
2/2/2019   DIT8990   1
2/2/2019   DIT6690   5
3/2/2019   DIE6770   2
4/2/2019   DIE9240   6
```

And table2 look like this

```
DATE      ID       CON
1/2/2019  DIE9240  B
2/2/2019  DIE9240  B
2/2/2019  DIT6690  B
3/2/2019  DIE6770  N
4/2/2019  DIE9240  N
```

So I want to relate those tables but the relation must be that the table2 ID must relate with the last date before it in the table1 ID

So basically the "DIE9240" in "4/2/2019" in table2 must relate to "DIE9240" in "2/2/2019" in table1. It cannot relate with "4/2/2019" because it is the same date (not before it), neither with "1/2/2019" because it is not the last date before it.

Is there anyway to do that? 
Much appreciated

Comment: What database are you using? You tagged several different ones...

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake. I deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the tables like this:

```
select *
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on 
  t2.id = t1.id 
  and
  t1.date = (select max(date) from table1 where id = t2.id and date < t2.date)
```

You can replace `*` with the column names that you want to select.
You have tagged your question with both MySql and SQLite and if it is SQLite that you are using, then the format of the dates in your sample data is not comparable and will not produce the correct results, as for SQLite dates are treated as strings.
You should change the format to `YYYY-MM-DD`. 
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/28GuKxGbq7FDpQ2g2RJTRa/0).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry I added sqlite somehow. While I think it is solved I still want to ask if there is some way to use relationships (using foreign keys) without joining the tables?